# Story involving the rumoured "whisper line": 2 points in a subterranean prison between which it is possible to communicate

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I have vague memories of a sci-fi story that involves "the whisper line" as a crucial plot device. The whisper line refers to 2 secret points in a highly oppressive prison institution between which it is possible for 2 inmates to hold a private conversation without anyone else's notice.

Sadly, all other plot details escape me.

I seem to remember these other features:

- Darkness, silence, and the routine of life in the institution
- The institution was submerged (subterranean?), possibly in a ravine, reserved for Jon Smith type dissidents
- Long quiet struggle and shifting fate for a mostly limp and powerless protagonist
- An unlikely bond between characters who grow to sympathise with each other in an almost animal sense (prior enemies drawn together in prison, I deduce)
- Slow, unsensationalist observation of the dehumanising effects of authoritarianism

The vivid feeling I have of the last 2 makes me think this could be an Ursula Le Guin novella, but I'm fairly sure I've read all her material in the last 5 years or so and haven't been able to retrieve this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "whisper line" features in Alfred Bester's [The Stars, My Destination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination). Gully Foyle has a Monte Cristo education in prison through whisper-line conversations with his teacher, Jizbella McQueen:

> "...My God, this must be real! You're talking the gutter lingo. You must be real. Who are you?"
>
> "Gully Foyle."
>
> "But you're not in my cell. You're not even near. Men are in the north quadrant of Gouffre Martel. Women are in the south. I'm South-900. Where are you?
>
> "North-111."
>
> "You're a quarter of a mile away. How can we - Of course! It's the Whisper Line. I always thought that was a legend, but it's true. It's working now... It's a miracle."
>
> "What's a miracle?"
>
> "There's an acoustical freak in Gouffre Martel... they happen in underground caves... a freak of echoes, passages and whispering galleries. Old-timers call it the Whisper Line..."