# Sole survivor of attack on mining vessel, abandoned by his employer, has ability to teleport

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, space

There's a story my grandpa use to tell me when I was younger, about the sole survivor of of an attack on a mining vessel in space. The man lives in space for months/years, ignored by the company he worked for and never rescued. Then when he thinks he is being rescued, it's actually another set of raiders who attack him and kidnap him.  He then wakes up in captivity in some sort of prison inside of an asteroid, and has a word tattooed on his forehead. My grandpa called him Ronin (that's what the tattoo on his forehead said) but I don't know what the character's real name is. Anyways, he learns that he has the ability to teleport after having a brush with death and decides to make his way back to Earth so that he can exact revenge on the mining company who abandoned him and left him floating to die.

Does anyone know what this story or book may be? My grandpa told it to me when I was little, he said that he got it from a book he use to love reading when he was younger. I'm assuming the book is very old (possibly pre 1940's as he was born in the 20s). I can't ask him as he is no longer alive. I'm also unsure as to whether or not all the details in the story he told me, are the same as in the original.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/story-involving-the-rumoured-whisper-line-2-points-in-a-subterranean-prison-b

Comment: @Otis I'm going to do the duplication the other way round, since this Q&A here will probably be more generally useful, focusing on the plot in general rather than just a single event in the story, than the older one.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That sounds like [The Stars My Destination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination) by Alfred Bester (1956):

"man lives in space for months/years, ignored by the company he worked for and never rescued."

> [Foyle] is marooned in space when the ship is attacked and he alone
>   survives. After six months of waiting for rescue, a passing spaceship,
>   the Vorga, also owned by the powerful Presteign industrial clan,
>   ignores his signal and abandons him

"in captivity in some sort of prison inside of an asteroid, and has a word tattooed on his forehead."

> is captured by a cargo cult in the Asteroid Belt which tattoos a hideous mask 
>   of a tiger on his face.

"he has the ability to teleport after having a brush with death"

> human beings could learn to teleport, or "jaunte" from point to point,

"make his way back to Earth so that he can exact revenge on the mining company who abandoned him"

> Foyle is enraged and is transformed into a man consumed by revenge

Comment: You may also know the book as "Tiger, Tiger".

Comment: Trivia - Walter Koenig's character's name in Babylon 5 was named after the author Alfred Bester.

Comment: Thank you, SO MUCH! That is the book!! Just ordered a copy. You rock :D

Comment: I don't remember the word "Ronin" from the book. The tattoo was not a name, it was more like a tiger's stripes. http://www.mrzdoinferno.com/tiger-tiger/

Comment: It's not "Ronin", it was "Nomad", with the Mars/Male O-with-arrow symbol ( &#9794; ) used for the "O" in "Nomad".